# Subscribing to a Websockets topic in Svelte

Tags: websocket, svelte

Previously, I've used Stomp for Websockets on the client side, subscribing to a particular topic.  For example:

```
    const url = "ws://localhost:8080";

    //const socket = new SockJS(url);
    const socket = new WebSocket(url);
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({}, function () {
        stompClient.subscribe('/topic/someTopic.*', function (output) {
            //parse the message
        });

        setConnected(true);
    }, function (err) {
        alert('Error: ' + err);
    });
```

In Svelte and Node Websockets, I see ways of connecting such as:

```
let socket
onMount(() => {
  socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000/chat")
  socket.addEventListener("open", ()=> {
    console.log("Opened")
  })
})
```

However, how would I subscribe to a particular topic?  Is there an alternative that would offer this?

Comment: What do you mean by "subscribe"? Do you mean listen to an event from the websocket?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern

Comment: https://socket.io/ provides a nice abstraction over websockets, its has concepts like rooms and custom events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute every javascript you want in a svelte component, just be sure that the DOM is yet rendered by calling it in the `onMount`:

```html
<script>
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';
  const URL = "ws://localhost:8080";
  
  const subscribeToTopic = () => {
    //const socket = new SockJS(URL);
    const socket = new WebSocket(URL);
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({}, function () {
        stompClient.subscribe('/topic/someTopic.*', function (output) {
            //parse the message
        });

        setConnected(true);
    }, function (err) {
        alert('Error: ' + err);
    });
  }

  onMount(() => {
    subscribeToTopic();
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Went a different direction ultimately instead of websockets, but I don't see an issue with this answer.